# Open file from Playbook app 

Tags: javascript, blackberry, air, blackberry-playbook

My playbook app downloads a zip file and opens it.

So can we create air objects on the playbook for file i/o operations since an api for the playbook I guess hasn't been developed.    For example:

```
var file =new air.File(path);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this document will help you understand the layout of the Playbook's file system, and which directories are available to you, as a developer:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Tablet-OS-SDK-for-Adobe-AIR/BlackBerry-PlayBook-File-System-Layout/ta-p/773327

After that, working with a file can be as simple as:

```
var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
var f:File = File.applicationDirectory;
f = f.resolvePath("myfile.txt");  
fs.open(f, FileMode.READ);  
// work with the file contents here
fs.close();
```

Comment: Thanxs for this. Isnt this actionscript code? So is there someway we can do the same in javascript because I am more of a javascript coder. Thanxs again for the response.

Comment: There may be a way of doing this with Javascript. Take a look at the PlayBook WebWorks SDK: http://us.blackberry.com/developers/tablet/webworks.jsp